# how to browse an image dynamically when user browse an image using previous div

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery mobile.

I have code in my page that browse  20 images using for loop.Depending on that "id" increases. This is my code

### HTML

```
          <?php 
     for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
     {
        $count=$i;
  ?>
    <div class="disp">            
      <div>
         <input class="noayudas" type="radio" name="im_OpcFile" id="im_OpcFile" value="<?php echo $count?>" <?php if($count==0){echo ' checked ';}?> />
      </div>

      <div >
         <input name="im_File_<?php echo $count?>" type="file"class="input noayudas" id="im_File_<?php echo $count?>" size="35">
      </div>

      <div>
         <input name="DescFile_<?php echo $count?>" id="DescFile_<?php echo $count?>" type="text" class="noayudas" maxlength="255"/>
      </div>
    </div>

       <?php } ?>
```

But i want to display it step by step i.e initially it should display a "disp" div only once, when the user browse an image then it should display or add "disp" divonce again.How to do this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially have only one "disp" div.

Then, since the value of the `input` element changes whenever the user selects an image, you can add a new "disp" div every time the value of the most recent input element changes.

You can use jQuery's [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector to select the last input element in a class and [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to trigger a function whenever the value of the input element changes.

Then to add a new "disp" div you can use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

Comment: Thnq it helped me lot.